# Access queryset values while setting up modelform

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is it possible to access a value from the queryset that was used to create the form class. For example I have the following view:

```
class MyView(View):

    position = Position()
    form_class = PortfolioForm
    PositionModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Position,
                                                fields=('symbol', 'direction', 'size'),
                                                form=form_class)

    def get(self, request):
        positions = self.position.get_user_positions_qs(user=request.user)
        portfolio = self.PositionModelFormSet(queryset=positions)
```

What I need is to be able to access the values that are passed to the PortfolioForm when creating the form. In other words, for each form in the formset there is a queryset that is used when instantiating it. I need to access the values in that queryset while setting up the form. For example the PortfolioForm would be something like:

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.ModelForm):

    value = get_value_from_queryset  # eg: access symbol field
    do_something_with_value(value)

    class Meta:

        model = Position
        fields = ['symbol', 'direction', 'size']
```

I was thinking something along the lines of accessing it somehow by overriding the form `__init__` method and using `self.instance` or `kwargs` but I haven't had any luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a ModelForm, form.instance already works.

In the form: self.instance

In the view: formset.form.instance